# Rasterstats in Python with .IMG files

Tags: python, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I am currently trying to use zonal_stats of the rasterstats package to get zonal statistics of processed satellite images. 
The data is stored as .img-format and i have a shapefile containing 1 polygon to test things.

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
IMG = 'S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20181104T054742_20181104T054807_024434_02AD7C_F5E1_pre.data\\Ratio.img'
SHP = 'Lake2.shp'
stats = zonal_stats(SHP,IMG,stats = "*")
```

When I run the code I get the following error message:

*AttributeError: 'rasterio._io.RasterReader' object has no attribute 'mask_flag_enums'*

Does anyone know how I could work around this? Previously I used ArcPy to get this done but I do not want to use it in further projects since not everyone has access to it.

Comment: Try specifying full paths to raster and shapefiles.

Comment: @BERA I did, but it did not help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, I think it was a problem in my setup. I reinstalled Anaconda and created a new environment using the data and it worked. 
Might have to do something with the fact that anaconda was installed on a HDD-Drive with FAT32-System instead of my SSD with NTFS. Fat32 seems not to be able to be used with files >4GB.